# Volt rb framework unable to connect to database

Tags: ruby, voltrb

when I fire `volt server` in the terminal, it gives me this error message

> Unable to connect to the database.  Volt will still run, but the
>   message bus requires a database connection to setup connections
>   between nodes, so the message bus has been disabled.  This means
>   updates will not be propigated between instances (server, console,
>   runners, etc...)

It didn't use to do this before. Even if I delete the repository, generate a new one, fresh, clean, untouched, it still gives me this error. Do I need to install a mongo DB viewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Volt expects MongoDB to be running locally, so install MongoDB and it should all work fine

Comment: Ah, definitely something worth including in the docs, especially for newer people =] It's so strange that it didn't throw this before, when I didn't have mongo, just the same. Is it preferable/better/more compatible to install it via homebrew rather than manually? does it matter much?

Comment: Yeah I recommend homebrew for everything on a mac, makes maintaining updates and dependencies easier

Comment: gotta follow http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/?_ga=1.183910502.1780934689.1435476430 carefully. when in doubt, call upon the power of `sudo`